# row-fluid vs row in twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `container-fluid` container element, and have been using `row` as opposed to `row-fluid`, admittedly out of ignorance.
 Now I am trying to replace the `row` class with `row-fluid` class, but have run into some questions. 
 First, I looked at how the `row-fluid` width is defined in the .less, and it's completely hieroglyphic to me, so would anyone care to explain?

More importantly, when I replace row with `row-fluid`, the height of the element collapses to 0 requiring me to include the .clearfix class in order for the row-fluid element to grow to contain its children columns. Why is this necessary, i.e. what is being floated and why when I replace `row` with `row-fluid`?

Comment: Bootstrap v3's `.row` = Bootstrap v2's `.row-fluid`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what elements you want to know the width of. The `row-fluid` class itself has a width of `100%`. The spans (or columns) have a relative width, set up in such a way that it combines to 100.

On the floating: all columns get floated, this is what makes it fluid. The only height related thing that a `row-fluid` does is setting `min-height: 30px`. This makes it by definition strange that anything would collapse to a height of 0.

I'd suspect the styling you've done on top of your old grid is what causes your main problems.

Comment: it seems strange that i got away with using row-fluid, since i just checked the .css file and it's not defined even though the layout is working, so i guess it just interprets row-fluid as row or something? anyways, thanks for your input, and my question is solved on account of row-fluid not existing. thank you!

Comment: @Derek So you are talking about Bootstrap 3 then? If that's the case, retag the question to `twitter-bootstrap-3` please.

Comment: I'm a little new here. But since the heart of the issue lies in the fact that row-fluid doesn't exist in BS3, should I still retag?

Answer (score 3):

This is what twitter bootstrap says:

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

Well, that is about `container` not `rows`, but if that explanation is not enough for you, then  [this is](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) the short explanation which should make things clear for you.

**NOTE:** If its version 2, then `row-fluid` itself is being `float: left` which would need to be cleared as you say.

This is because Fluid grids utilize nesting differently: each nested level of columns should add up to 12 columns. This is because the fluid grid uses percentages, not pixels, for setting widths.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Bootstrap 3 doesn't have a `row-fluid` class, so I suspect he is asking about Bootstrap 2.

Comment: @gpgekko Yes it would be for version 2 but I found the explanation for the `clearfix` thing in docs of version 3, so I just linked that in answer as well :)

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 2.x to 3.0 class change**
Bootstrap 2.x-->**.row-fluid** and Bootstrap 3.0 -->**.row**